# Proof verification: continuous function, $f(x) > m$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I hope someone can verify my proofs.

Given: $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Let $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

a) Let $f(c) > 0$ and $m$ be a real number such that $0 < m < f(c)$. Prove there exists a $\delta$ such that for every $x \in B(c; \delta)$, $f(x) > m$.

Proof: Let $\epsilon = f(c) - m$. Then $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous there exists a $\delta$ for this $\epsilon$ such that $x \in B(c; \delta) \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(c)| < f(c) - m \Rightarrow m - f(c) < f(x) - f(c) < f(c) - m \Rightarrow f(x) > m$.

b) Let $f(c) \neq 0$. Prove there exists a $m>0$ and a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in B(c; \delta)$, $|f(x)| > m$.

Proof: We proved this for $f(c) > 0$ in part a. Assume $f(c) < 0$. Let $m$ be real such that $0 < m < |f(c)|$. Let $\epsilon = -m - f(c)$. Then $\epsilon > 0$. Continuity of $f$ ensures there exists a $\delta$ such that $x \in B(c; \delta) \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(c)| < -m - f(c) \Rightarrow f(x) - f(c) < -m - f(c) \Rightarrow f(x) < -m \Rightarrow |f(x)| > m$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks fine for me. Bravo!.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is fine, but you could shorten the proof of b).
If $f(c) < 0$, you could just apply the result of a) to the function $-f$.